# Detect if flash is disabled in Mozilla Firefox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, firefox

Does anyone have an example of a script that can work reliably well on Mozilla Firefox to detect if the flash player is installed but disabled.

I am able to detect whether it is installed or not but i want to know the case when it is installed and disabled in Firefox.

Comment: abpatil i went through that post, its not a duplicate....